# Finding out unknown matched words

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a regex pattern:

```
import regex as re
re.sub(r'(.*)\bHello (.*) BGC$\b', "OTR", 'Hello People BGC')
```

This will replace to give `OTR`, but how do I find out what the matched characters are within the `(.*)`?

Using `regex==2016.1.10`, `Python 3.5.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile the pattern and then call `match()` and `sub()` separately:

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'^Hello (.*?) BGC$')
>>> s = 'Hello People BGC'
>>> pattern.match(s).group(1)
'People'
>>> pattern.sub("OTR", s)
'OTR'
```